# postgres update an updatedAt field with RULE

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying to set automaticaly an updatedAt field on postgres

Here my dump file:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Product" (
  "id" uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  "createdAt" timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  "updatedAt" timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  "name" TEXT NOT NUll UNIQUE,
  "type" "ProductType" NOT NULL
);


CREATE RULE set_updatedAt AS ON UPDATE TO "Product"
  DO UPDATE "Product" SET "updatedAt" = NOW() WHERE NEW.id = OLD.id AND NEW."updatedAt" = OLD."updatedAt";
```

On UPDATE, I'm receiving the error "infinite recursion detected in rules for relation "Product""

I do not understand how it's possible whith this kind of condition "NEW.id = OLD.id AND NEW."updatedAt" = OLD."updatedAt""

Any idea, how can I perform a treatment like that?

version : postgres 10

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First don't use rules they will only give you headaches. Second the reason it failed is an `UPDATE` is both a `DELETE(OLD)` and an `INSERT(NEW)`. You logic is saying if the `OLD` and `NEW` record equal each other for `id` and `updatedAt` then `UPDATE updatedAt`. When you do the `UPDATE` the `OLD` and `NEW` values will always match as you have not actually updated `updatedAt` yet. This drops you into the infinite recursion of updating because you updated. If you want to do this use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger and function.

Answer (score 0):

When you do an `UPDATE`, your `RULE` will be triggered. That makes an `UPDATE`, which triggers your `RULE`. That makes an `UPDATE`, which triggers your `RULE`...

I am not quite sure, but I guess, that your `RULE` `UPDATE` will not be persisted until the operation is finished, as in a normal transaction. So, each new `RULE` call works on the old, non-persisted data. Therefore, every `RULE` call checks the same condition as before and this creates an infinite loop.

However: [Please think about using RULES](https://www.depesz.com/2010/06/15/to-rule-or-not-to-rule-that-is-the-question/), anyway

Answer (score 0):

Yes,

I had a doubt on the feasibility.
You answer my question. I soluced the issue with trigger

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION set_updatedAt() RETURNS trigger AS
$set_updatedAt$
BEGIN
    IF NEW."updatedAt" = OLD."updatedAt" THEN
        NEW."updatedAt" = NOW();
    END IF;
    RETURN NEW;
END;
$set_updatedAt$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS "Product" (
  "id" uuid PRIMARY KEY,
  "createdAt" timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  "updatedAt" timestamp(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP),
  "name" TEXT NOT NUll UNIQUE,
  "type" "ProductType" NOT NULL
);

CREATE TRIGGER table_update
BEFORE UPDATE ON "Product"
FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE set_updatedAt();
```

Comment: If you just want `updatedAt` reset every time an `UPDATE` is done the above can be simplified to `NEW."updatedAt" = NOW();` without the `IF` test.